# How to use a CSS animation within a JavaScript plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to highlight some text on using a CSS animation and a time delay.

This would normally be fairly straight forward. I know the following code works as I have tested and ran it.

```css
.tester {
  background-color: rgba(199, 220, 101, 0); 
  animation: example 1s linear 6s 1; 
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: rgba(199, 220, 101, 0);
  }
  100% {
    background: rgba(199, 220, 101, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  In writing <span class="tester">this book</span> I have drawn consciously and unconsciously from one million outside sources.
</p>
```

But I'm running a JavaScript plugin called typed.js. 
This means the text types out. But the effect I want is the text to type out (this is fine) and then after a time delay some of the text to be highlighted.
But my CSS animations are not working within typed.js.

If you go to 
http://www.thebooktheworldwrote.com/

i explain the problem. 
The effect i would like is the highlight of 'good people' after 4 seconds. Just adding -webkit- stuff so 'good people' highlights. At the minute it is not.

This is currently impossible with the typing effect. The best i can do is highlight some sections from the word go,

View https://jsfiddle.net/harrydry/p4ev1nj2/3/ for the best look at the problem.

Comment: Please describe your problem in a more detailed manner.

Comment: hi i have updated the question with a web-page explaining my problem better :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
.tester{
    animation-name: highlight;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    background-color: green;
}

@keyframes highlight{
    from {background-color: green;}
    to {background: lightgreen;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes highlight{
    from {background-color: green;}
    to {background: lightgreen;}
}
@-moz-keyframes highlight{
    from {background-color: green;}
    to {background: lightgreen;}
}
```

With this you get fade effect for background color change.

Full example here https://jsfiddle.net/2r1hs76u/

If you don't want fade effect use `animation-delay` like this https://jsfiddle.net/2r1hs76u/2/

Comment: You're welcome. If it solved your problem you should accept answer by clicking on checkmark or upvote if it was useful. That way we both get some reputation and help other visitors to recognize best solutions.

Comment: I would love to vote you up !!

Maybe I was being silly but i couldn't get your idea to work. 

https://jsfiddle.net/harrydry/p4ev1nj2/3/

Check out the j-fiddle and if you manage to sort it then i will upvote you :) 

enjoy the day and thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: you just need to implement my code, nothing more https://jsfiddle.net/p4ev1nj2/4/

Comment: thanks for your work - just testing now. then i will upvote etc 

sorry i asked you to do it again. i must have been making a mistake the first time cause the code wasn't working.

Comment: i tried to mark as the correct answer and upvote but it said something about less than 15 reputation. Hopefully it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Could you give us some more information?

Try to make the text you want highlighted to make the font bold and also check out this github page, you probably gonna need to do some small editing to type.js, as in configurations related to timeout

https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/blob/master/README.md

Comment: thanks a lot 

i have updated the problem with the website effect i would like. 

please check it out and maybe offer a drop more feedback.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense. But i'm very poor at Javascript. I don't think I'm talented enough to alter typed.js. 

i emailed matt the developer, with my problem and he hasn't got back to me yet. 

is there a work around ? 

What changes should i make relting to timeout ? 

thanks a lot

Comment: Well, what you could do is perhaps make slices of ur text and having them all in different classes to prevent the css applied after all text is typed.
Like creating multiple div's instead. I don't know or it work's as I've got no time to test it out now. It isn't perhaps the most professional fix but it could work. I'll see later or you solved your problem else I'll make an attempt to fix it.

Ur .tester css animation should work fine on it using that way, although in theory atleast.